# I18n + next js 14 app routing при переключении на другую локаль в строке браузера руками 404, а по клику на ссылку все ок

Tags: next.js, i18n

Локаль не переключается при ручном вводе другой локали в строку браузера, только клики по ссылке переключают.
Ещё заметил, что не происходит так как в документации link href=/ locale=en и должно перейти на /en
Переходит на /.
Настройка по документации next.Config и все.
Возникла мысль вручную установить локаль, но оказалось, что способ описанный в документации через useRouter удалён в next 14.
В документации по миграции написано что мы все удалили а как делать смотрите документацию i18n. И ссылка туда откуда пришёл. Замкнутый круг.
Если вручную определить из URL через usepathername?)) язык, а затем по этим данным выдать контент, то получишь ошибку несоответствия значения локали на сервере с локалью на клиенте.потому что клика не было а через изменение юрл руками i18n значение активной локали не переключает.
Короче как установить вручную локаль в next js 14 на сервере для i18n. По URL.